# Как вставить нестандартную формулу в Word '10?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office, формулы

Нужно набрать следующую формулу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В стандартных формулах есть знак суммы, произведения, пересечения и объединения, но пустого шаблона для вставки своего символа нет.

Если попытаться использовать макрос, где `8853` - символ `xor` для набора `Cambria Math` (стандартный шрифт в формулах):

```
With Selection.OMaths(1).Functions.Add(Selection.Range, _
    wdOMathFunctionNary)
    .Nary.Char = 8853
    .Nary.Grow = False
    .Nary.SubSupLim = False
    .Nary.HideSub = False
    .Nary.HideSup = False
End With
```

Получаю следующее сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли возможность как-то обойти это препятствие и набрать-таки формулу, не вставляя ее как картинку?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно использовать матрицу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В средний плейсхолдер добавить нужный знак:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В верхний:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нижний:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Справа добавить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее заполнить,в лишние плейсхолдеры ввести пробелы и средний знак выровнять с помощью пробелов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проделайте эти операции во время записи макроса и по результатам его анализа поймёте, как сделать программно.